# xpath for selecting elements having a child value specified in a list

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Consider the following case:

```
<xsl:variable name="list">
   <row>
     <webid>2</webid>
   </row>
   <row>
     <webid>3</webid>
   </row>
   <row>
     <webid>4</webid>
   </row>
</xsl:variable>

<!--pseudo code, not sure if it will work in real time-->
<xsl:variable name="addr" select="addresses/item[not(id=$list/webid)]"/>
```

I want to filter those addresses items which have an id not in the `$list webid collection`. Will the expression I posted do? Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0 a variable declaration like that is a *result tree fragment*, not a node set, and the only thing you can do with it is `copy-of` or `value-of` - you can't navigate into it with XPath expressions.  You need to either

1. Use an extension function such as [exslt:node-set](http://exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html) to turn the RTF into a real node set or
2. Use a trick with `document('')` to access the style sheet itself as an XML document

Option 2 only works in cases like your example, where the variable value is static XML.  If you have a variable whose value is built using `xsl:` commands or attribute value templates, e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="allNames">
  <xsl:for-each select="name">
    <person name="{.}" />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

then you'd have to use a `node-set` function.  The `document('')` approach would give you the actual `xsl:for-each` element and a literal value of `{.}` for the name attribute, rather than the result of evaluating it.

**Option 1**

Add `xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="exslt"` to your `<xsl:stylesheet>` tag, then use

```
<xsl:variable name="addr" select="addresses/item[
     not(id=exslt:node-set($list)/row/webid)]"/>
```

**Option 2**

```
<xsl:variable name="addr" select="addresses/item[
     not(id=document('')//xsl:variable[name='list']/row/webid)]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I put not(addresses/item[id=$list/webid])